# Saving Image from a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, bitmapimage

I'm trying to save a bitmap from the panel, but the saved image is with the program's bar...

How can I do for save an image onyly with an specified panel?

Here is my code:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
  this.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, panel1.ClientRectangle);
  bitmap.Save("C:\\" + pagAtual + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the Panel control instead (also, use the ClientSize properties and dispose of the bitmap when done):

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, 
                                  panel1.ClientSize.Height)) {
  panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, panel1.ClientRectangle);
  bitmap.Save("C:\\" + pagAtual + ".bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

Comment: Didnt work ... I have only white image after saving.

Comment: @user2179427 Can't see your code.  Obviously, your panel doesn't have anything in it the DrawToBitmap can pick up.

Comment: @LarsTech I can clearly see drawings on my panel. How is it possible that it cannot pick up anything? What is the proper way to draw to panel so DrawToBitmap can pick it up?

Comment: @user2179427 Again, I can't see your code.  I can only guess you are using CreateGraphics, so if you are, don't.  Use the panel's paint event.